# Entity Framework 6 Separate Project - Editor Templates not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have setup 2 projects in my solution:

1. MVC5 Web Application
2. Class Library (Entity Framework 6 Code First Approach)

I am now trying to setup Editor Templates for a form I am working on, but they are not working.  The form itself exists in a partial view.  Thus far, I have tried the following:

I have created a DateTime Editor Template inside of my MVC5 Web Application (Views/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml).  The code for my template looks like this:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.HasValue ?
    Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp", style = "width:100px" })
```

I have placed a UI Hint for the property in my model:

```
[UIHint("DateTime")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

That did not work, so I tried adding the following code to my Partial View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, "DateTime")
```

**At this point, I believe I'm having problems because my EF Model is in a separate project.  If that is the case, then how does one implement editor templates in this scenario?**

Comment: I think the view needs to be in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml

Comment: @Tommy this is exactly the mistake I was making.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good deal!  I added as an answer so if anyone else has a similar problem, they can find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an EditorTemplate across your project, you should store the template in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (you will need to create one as it is not a default project folder).  This will allow the view engine to find your custom Editor template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe does not work because you have in model DateTime and in editor DateTime? nullable?